# Proof of equicontinuity via uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, equicontinuity

I am studying for an entrance exam in August and I am trying to review and cover the real analysis section. I came across this problem on one of the past exams and I am having some trouble with it.

Let $G(x, y)$ be a continuous function on $R^2$ and suppose for each positive
integer $k$, that $g_k$ is a continuous function defined on [0, 1] with the property that $|g_k(y)| \leq 1$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$. Now define

$$f_k(x) := \int_{0}^{1}g_k(y)G(x, y) dy.$$
Prove that the sequence ${f_k}$ is equicontinuous on [0, 1].

So for the problem above, given that $[0,1]$  is compact, I think that it is sufficient to show that {${f_k(x)}$} is uniformly convergent on the interval $[0,1]$. How would I show that {${f_k(x)}$} is uniformly convergent on {${f_k(x)}$}?

Comment: Hint: prove that for each $x$, and $\epsilon >0$ there is a small interval $I_x$ around $x$ such that for all $x’ \in I_x$, $0 \leq y \leq 1$, $|G(x’,y)-G(x,y)| \leq \epsilon$. Prive that such an $I_x$ is an “interval of $\epsilon$-continuity” for each $f_k$.

Comment: Whoops, I goofed. I accidentally wrote "uniformly continuous" instead of "uniformly convergent" in the last paragraph. My mistake, I fixed it. So do your comments still apply?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot prove convergence. Instead, take $\epsilon >0$ and  choose $\delta >0$ such that $|G(x,y)-G(x',y')| <\epsilon$ whenever $\|(x,y)-(x',y')\| <\delta$. This is possible because any continuous function on the compact space $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is unifomly continuous. From this you get $|f_k(x)-f_k(y)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y| <\delta$ which is the definition of equicontinuity.